# Django Python - SQLDecodeError on deleted attribute after Migration

Tags: python, django

I am currently using Django2.2 with Djongo1.2.38, and running into a SQLDecodeError - DuplicateKey after I changed the model and ran a migration.

I had a model, `Project`, that had an attribute called `customer_po`.

I removed this attribute and changed around a bunch of attributes, and made/applied a migration.

I can see in the output from making my migration this line:

`- Remove field customer_po from project`

I applied my migration and it was successful.

I created a new project object, and when I go to create a second one I am met with this error:

```
FAILED SQL: INSERT INTO "crud_project" ("id", "project_number", "purchase_order", "quotation_number", "client_name", "project_name", "project_owner_id", "project_manager_id") VALUES (%(0)s, %(1)s, %(2)s, %(3)s, %(4)s, %(5)s, %(6)s, %(7)s)

Params: (UUID('eb7184ee-cc0c-4765-a04c-455a2a70af15'), '123', '12345', '321312', 'Hello', 'Ads', UUID('30f86ee3-e1b7-4820-a39e-c996a1799254'), UUID('c29f869a-e629-46b3-9cc6-cace7de1b987'))

Pymongo error: 
{'writeErrors': 
  [{'index': 0, 'code': 11000, 'keyPattern': {'customer_po': 1}, 
  'keyValue': {'customer_po': None}, 
  'errmsg': 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: psm.crud_project index: customer_po_1 dup key: { customer_po: null }', 'op': {'id': UUID('eb7184ee-cc0c-4765-a04c-455a2a70af15'), 'project_number': '123', 'purchase_order': '12345', 'quotation_number': '321312', 'client_name': 'Hello', 'project_name': 'Ads', 'project_owner_id': UUID('30f86ee3-e1b7-4820-a39e-c996a1799254'), 'project_manager_id': UUID('c29f869a-e629-46b3-9cc6-cace7de1b987'), '_id': ObjectId('5ed7c79ddfacbb6c0315927a')}}], 'writeConcernErrors': [], 'nInserted': 0, 'nUpserted': 0, 'nMatched': 0, 'nModified': 0, 'nRemoved': 0, 'upserted': []}
```

Even though the attribute is not in the params, or inside the model anymore, I am getting an error for duplicate key.

Does this have to do with a created index on the `Project` collection, that still has the old attribute names?

Thanks

Edit: My migration file

```
# Generated by Django 2.2 on 2020-06-03 15:10

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('crud', '0013_auto_20200519_1437'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='project',
            old_name='customer_project_name',
            new_name='project_name',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='project',
            name='customer_billing_manager',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='project',
            name='customer_name',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='project',
            name='customer_po',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='project',
            name='customer_project_team_name',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='project',
            name='client_name',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='project',
            name='project_manager',
            field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, related_name='managed_projects', to='crud.Manager'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='project',
            name='project_number',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, unique=True),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='project',
            name='project_owner',
            field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, related_name='owned_projects', to='crud.Manager'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='project',
            name='purchase_order',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50, unique=True),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='project',
            name='quotation_number',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, unique=True),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: how does your migration file looks like, it could be problem with djongo, you can manually write query to remove column, why is it tagged with mysql-error if there is no mysql

Comment: Sorry remove that tag, was an accident. Will add my migration file now.

Comment: @iklinac Looking under the `__schema__` collection in my database, the model has not been updated to match my newest migration.

Comment: ./manage showmigrations --list, does it show as migrated, you can retry it by removing it from django_migrations table

Comment: [X] 0014_auto_20200603_1510 Yes it does.

Comment: you could debug it with sqlmigrate to see sql that is been run to find out what is going wrong, and maybe post issue on djongo git if you see something unusual happening

Comment: Thanks I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by deleting the index `customer_po_1`.

I am not entirely sure what happened, but I have a feeling that there were 2 indexes created for this field, `customer_po` and `customer_po_`. When I applied my migrations, one of them was deleted but the other wasn't.

The above is a total hunch, not entirely sure what happened.